# Remote connection refused by mysql on vbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mysql

I am currently using ubuntu server on a virtual box machine to have a secondary environment for testing.  The server also has mysql-server installed but I would like to manage it through mysql workbench on my host machine except when trying to connect the the remote host I am refused a connection.

HOST:

```
telnet 192.168.56.8 3306
Trying 192.168.56.8...
Connected to 192.168.56.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
EHost '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Trying to connect

```
mysql -h 192.168.56.8:3306 -u root
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.56.8:3306'
```

VBOX:

mysql.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
...

[mysqld]
bind-address            = 192.168.56.8
...
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.8
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

checking port

```
netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.8:3306       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: What are your network configurations on the VM?

Comment: everything below "VBOX:" in the question.  I can pink the server fine from my host machine and serve websites but no luck with mysql remote connection.

Comment: answer: mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.56.1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried to connect like this

```
mysql -h 192.168.56.8:3306 -u root
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.56.8:3306'
```

The IP and the port are supposed to be separate

```
mysql -h 192.168.56.8 -P3306 -u root
```

Since the default port for mysql is 3306, you need not specify it

```
mysql -h 192.168.56.8 -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grant all on *.* to root@'192.168.56.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

3306 is default mysql port. So your command should be like this:

`mysql -h 192.168.56.8 -u root`

Otherwise, you can try this on your mysql server:

`iptables -F` (the iptables restored when the machine is restarted)

or

`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

then try to connect again.